# Move files based on filename into directory Year/Month/Day

Tags: files, timestamps, mv

I have files in the format `YYYY_MM_DD_HH:MM:SS.swf` that dump into a folder `/home/user/dump/`

I want to move these files into a new directory tree `/home/user/save/year/month/day/` based on the `YYYY_MM_DD` from the filename. Alternatively, if these can be modified by the file modification date, that is acceptable as well. I've found a couple other scripts on here, but they don't seem to have all the info I'm looking for.

Comment: what did you do so far ? What is failing ?

Comment: I've tried [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261888/help-creating-script-to-move-files-based-on-date-or-filename) script on the first response, but it spits out an error on line 21. I'm not sure if it would output the /year/month/day/ structure.

Comment: All files hold this same pattern. No, no directories should be ignored. Hopefully the format is something like 2016/02/29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```shell
while read file
 do 
     f=$(basename $file)
     year=$(echo "$f"|cut -f1 -d_)
     day=$(echo "$f"|cut -f3 -d_)
     month=$(echo "$f"|cut -f2 -d_)
     new_dir="/home/user/save/$year/$month/$day"
     mkdir -p "$new_dir"
     mv "$file" "$new_dir"
done < <(find /home/user/dump -type f -name "*_*_*_*:*:*.swf")
```

Comment: I ran this script, and it created /home/user/dump/home/user/save/2016/02/file.swf -- it is missing the day folder. I might be missing something here but this is close

Comment: Perhaps you're wrong about the file format?  Because this should just work.

Comment: Show me the output of ls where the files live perhaps?

Comment: This is actually very close. 'for file in $(find /home/user/dump/ -name "*.swf")
do
  year=$(echo ${file}|cut -d_ -f1)
  month=$(echo ${file}|cut -d_ -f2)
  day=$(echo ${file}|cut -d_ -f3)
  if [ ! -d /home/user/dump_save/${year}/${month}/${day} ]
  then
    mkdir -p /home/user/dump_save/${year}/${month}/${day}
  fi
  mv ${file} /home/user/dump_save/${year}/${month}/${day}
done
' This duplicates the directory, though and creates 'user/dump_save/home/user/dump/2016/02/day' where the day is working correctly. ls of where the files lives /home/user/dump/2016_02_26_06:51:40.swf

Comment: It shouldn't, that isn't what the code says to do, are you editing the code?  How are you running it?  Both answers given to you were correct as far as I can see, so my instinct is that you are leaving out info, or doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Try my code again, I see where there may have been a problem.  It should work now.

Comment: That aside, the whole `while..read` and `echo | cut` three times is - just like Mel's answer - a terrible approach to solve this...

Comment: Why is it terrible?

Comment: The parts edited are the new_dir address and find address to match my directory. For some reason it creates a new tree /home/user/save/home/user/2016/02/29/, but otherwise it is working. EDIT: whatever edit you changed in the source script, it is now working.

Comment: don_crissti, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's a fine approach, he's just being hypercritical.  This is a one liner, an elegant solution would be an actual script.

Comment: It sure is a lot more than I could create. Thanks Gregg. Also, for posterity, can you tell me what you changed from the original script?

Comment: I did have an error, I was naming the new directories based on the full path of the old file instead of the file name.  I added a variable $f which points to the basename of the file to fix that.

Comment: The other guy Mel made the same kind of error.  Find will return an absolute path if you give it one, we both neglected to consider that.

Comment: Note that this would choke on file names containing spaces and other special characters. Also using pipes to `cut` to process strings is rather slow.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Perl-based `rename` (sometimes known as `prename`) you can do this with a single command:

```
cd /home/user/dump
rename -v 'use File::Path qw(make_path); m!^((....)_(..)_(..)_(.*))!; my $d = "$2/$3/$4"; make_path($d); s!^!$d/!' *
```

Actually this is a fairly ugly (mis)use of `rename`. For each file, the code runs as follows

1. Include a system library that allows for directory path creation
2. Match against the `YYYY_MM_DD` structure at the beginning of the filename
3. Create the corresponding directory path `YYYY/MM/DD` (if necessary)
4. Move (rename) the file into its `YYYY/MM/DD` directory, leaving its name unchanged

Answer (score 2):

### Zsh

Use the [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function to move or rename files matched by a wildcard expression. There's no built-in way to create the destination directory, so I provide a function to do it.

```
autoload -U zmv
mkdir_mv () {
  mkdir -p -- ${(P)#:h}
  mv -- $@
}
cd /home/user/dump
zmv -p mkdir_mv '(????)_(??)_(??)_??:??:??.swf' '/home/user/save/$1/$2/$3/$f'
```

### POSIX shell

If you need a portable solution, use a shell loop over the files, and shell string manipulation to extract the parts of the file names.

```
cd /home/user/dump
for f in ????_??_??_??:??:??.swf; do
  year=${f%%_*}; suffix=${f#*_}
  month=${suffix%%_*}; suffix=${suffix#*_}
  day=${suffix%%_*}
  mkdir -p "/home/user/save/$year/$month/$day"
  mv "$f" "/home/user/save/$year/$month/$day/$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```shell
for file in $(find /home/user/dump/ -name "*.swf")
do
  year=$(echo ${file}|cut -d_ -f1)
  month=$(echo ${file}|cut -d_ -f2)
  day=$(echo ${file}|cut -d_ -f3)
  if [ ! -d /home/user/save/${year}/${month}/${day} ]
  then
    mkdir -p /home/user/save/${year}/${month}/${day}
  fi
  mv ${file} /home/user/save/${year}/${month}/${day}
done
```

Comment: This is close - it moves the files, but 'doubles' the directory tree, i.e. saves the files in /home/user/save/home/user/save/year/month. Also, it omits the 'Day' folder

Comment: Then your file name format is not what you presented it to be, i.e. `YYYY_MM_DD_HH:MM:SS.swf`. Please post a section of the output from  `ls -l  /home/user/dump/"

Comment: File format example '"/home/user/dump/2016_02_26_06:51:40.swf"' or '2016_02_27_09:57:14.swf'

Comment: Note that this would choke on file names containing spaces and other special characters. Also using pipes to `cut` to process strings is rather slow.